# Capitalisation of “wie” in “Wie geht’s?” and “ich” right after salutation

Tags: capitalization

I’ve heard conflicting views on this one from German speakers. Which is correct (in an email, for example):

> Wie geht’s?

or

> wie geht’s?

Similarly, for sentences starting with *ich:* One of my friends tells me that it should not be capitalized (even though it is the start of a sentence). When else is this rule true?

Comment: Sentences almost always start with a captial letter. [Are you talking about the first sentence after the salutation/greeting?](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Titel.html?lang=en)

Comment: Ah yes, I was unaware of this rule but turns out this was the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You start sentences always with a capital letter.

In this example:

> Hallo Andreas,
>
> wie geht es dir?

you do *not* start a new sentence, therefore you are not supposed to use a capital letter.